# How to declare public variable from protected method in asp net?

Tags: asp.net

I have database with images in folder on my server. To display this images I'am using DataList control. ItemTemplate include also a LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="wybierzZdjecieBtn" OnClick="choosePhotoButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PhotoLinkAddress")%>' CssClass="wybierzZdjecieButton" runat="server">Choose photo</asp:LinkButton>
```

To receiving Value from LinkButton CommandArgument i'am using this method:

```
protected void choosePhotoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton button = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string photoLinkAddressVar = button.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Response.Write(PhotoLinkAddressVar);
}
```

This works fine, no problems. But this is not what I want achieve. My intentions is send this variable "PhotoLinkAddressVar" to this method:

```
protected void addNewNews_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string trescStatus = "czeka";
    string autor = Session["userName"].ToString();
    DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
    string dataFormat = "";
    dataFormat = data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm");

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["wiadomosciConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        string dodaj = "Insert into News (TytulNews, TrescNews, Autor, Data, Kategoria, Dotyczy, PhotoLinkAddress, Status) values (@TytulNews, @TrescNews, @Autor, @Data, @Kategoria, @Dotyczy, @PhotoLinkAddress, @Status)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(dodaj, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TytulNews", tytulNewsTextBox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrescNews", trescTextBox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Autor", autor);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", dataFormat);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kategoria", kategoria.SelectedValue.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dotyczy", dotyczy.SelectedValue.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhotoLinkAddress", photoLinkAddressVar);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", trescStatus);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

User have to choose photo before press "Add News", because if He doesn't do that, he will receive error message. I dont know, how do that. I Was trying declare some kind public variable before PageLoad and do something like this:

```
protected void choosePhotoButtonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton button = (LinkButton)(sender);
    photoLinkAddressVar = button.CommandArgument.ToString();

}
```

but that method won't declare the variable. Do You have any idea, how can I achieve that ?.

Comment: Ok, i found solution. In "choosePhotoButton' I'am creating a Session["photo"] with photo address link. And when I'am pressing "Add News" after Executing Query Session is Removing. I'am not sure is good method, but works :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use also the `ViewState`.

```
protected void choosePhotoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton button = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string photoLinkAddressVar = button.CommandArgument.ToString();
    View["photoLinkAddressVar"]=photoLinkAddressVar;
    Response.Write(PhotoLinkAddressVar);
}
```

Then in the `addNewNews_Click` method, you coukld retrieve this value with the following way:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhotoLinkAddress", ViewState["photoLinkAddressVar"]);
```

For further documantation about `ViewState` please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx).